# Datastax: why removing built-in DataImportHandler from Solr?

Tags: datastax-enterprise

One of the nice features of Solr is its ability to import sql data. However its feature is removed in the bundled version in Datastax. Manually adding the missing jar to $SOLR_HOME/lib and configurations files only make it appear in the Solr portal page, but it still does not work. Datastax is hiding Solr log to some unknown place not documented in its official doc, making troubleshooting more difficult. Has anybody been able to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience, but the current releases of DataStax Enterprise do not support the Solr Data Import Handler. This is a known problem. We expect to have it fixed in an upcoming release (likely in a 3.2.x release.)

DataStax Enterprise tightly integrates Solr, so there are configuration differences that need to be taken into account when configuring plugins for Solr. Configuring of DIH will be fixed and documented in an upcoming release.